# How to save and get plain text data in amazon aws s3 bucket using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3

I am trying to save plain text data at **AWS S3** bucket using **ASP.NET MVC** can you help to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

**Save and GET data in aws s3 bucket in asp.net mvc :-**

To save plain text data at amazon s3 bucket.

1.First you need a bucket created on aws than

2.You need your aws credentials like a)aws key b) aws secretkey c) region

// code to save data at aws // Note you can get access denied error. to remove this please check AWS account and give //read and write rights

Name space need to add from NuGet package

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

 var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(awsKey, awsSecretKey);          
                try`
                {
                    AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.APSouth1);
                    // simple object put
                    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
                    {
                        ContentBody = "put your plain text here",
                        ContentType = "text/plain",
                        BucketName = "put your bucket name here",
                        Key = "1"
                        //put unique key to uniquly idenitify your data
                        // you can pass here any data with unique id like primary key 
                        //in db
                    };              
                    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
                   
                }
                catch(exception ex)
                {
                     //
                }
```

Now go to your AWS account and check the bucket you can get data with "1" Name in the AWS s3 bucket. Note:- if you get any other issue please ask me a question here will try to resolve it.

**To get data from AWS s3 bucket:-**

```
 try
            {              
                var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(awsKey, awsSecretKey);
                AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.APSouth1);
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = "1"// because we pass 1 as unique key while save 
                            //data at the s3 bucket
                };

                using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new 
                 StreamReader(response.ResponseStream);
                    vccEncryptedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```